# Late binding? Field vs Property. Self vs Static

Tags: java

This has bothered me for a long time, so I thought I'd go ahead and ask.

If I write

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
            new Shape();
            new Triangle();
    }

    public static class Shape
    {
            static String name = "shape";

            Shape()
            {
                    printName();
            }

            public void printName()
            {
                    System.out.println( name() );
            }

            public String name()
            {
                    return name;
            }
    }

    public static class Triangle extends Shape
    {
            static String name = "triangle";

            public String name()
            {
                    return name;
            }
    }
}
```

then the output is

```
shape
triangle
```

But if I write

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
            new Shape();
            new Triangle();
    }

    public static class Shape
    {
            static String name = "shape";

            Shape()
            {
                    printName();
            }

            public void printName()
            {
                    System.out.println( name );
            }

    }

    public static class Triangle extends Shape
    {
            static String name = "triangle";
    }
}
```

then the output is

```
shape
shape
```

In the first version, I have to copy/paste the same function getName() over and over into every subclass. There's has to be a better way. What do I need to change in the second example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

static fields aren't accessible from parent classes. The class `Shape` doesn't "see" the static field `name` of the class `Triangle` and uses his own static field `name`.

**UPD:** You ask: what do you need to change in the second example? More specifically, your first example is a correct "fixing" of your second example. The only correct way is using some getter method like your `name()` method.

**UPD2:** (from my commentary): Well, another way: forgive about any kind of field `name`. Use instead a method called `name()` (not static!) which will return in each class the needed name. Just `return "shape";` or `return "triangle"` in them;

Comment: So I have to copy "public String name(){ return name; }" into every single subclass? Surely there is a better way.

Comment: Whenever you reference an static field you statically bind to that concrete field. Static fields do not get overriden with inheritance, so you end up with two different name fields (one in Shape, one in Triangle). 

The name() method of Shape is statically bound to Shape.name field and the one in triangle is statically bound to Triangle.name field. No polymorphism in there

Comment: @beardedlinuxgeek, if you want to save static nature of field `name`, your could for example override `printName()` method. But I don't think, that this is a better way. As for me, in practice in such situations I always create some getter for such static fields.

Comment: Ignore the fact that its a static property. If you change "static String name" to "String name" then you get the same result.

Comment: Of course you will gain the same result! Because parent class `Shape` use reference to static field `name` in `printName` implementation.

Comment: I know in PHP you can write "static:" instead of "self:" to do what I'm talking about (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). I still can't believe I need to copy/paste an identical function into every subclass..but I guess I can live it.

Comment: Well, another way: forgive about any kind of field `name`. Use instead method called `name()` (not static!) which will return in each class needed name. Just `return "shape";` or `return "triangle";`

Comment: See my second answer. This is another (but funny) way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have already answered this question in a negative way. But as a kind of joke and funny solution (**which will work!!!**) you could change your `printName()` method to this one:

```
public void printName() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    System.out.println((String)(this.getClass().getDeclaredField("name").get(this)));
}
```

This is only one change, which you have to do in the **second** example for gaining the output

```
shape
triangle
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great illustration of how Java resolves names to values. You have two variables called `name`, one in `Shape` and one in `Triangle`. Even though `Triangle` is a subclass of `Shape` *these are completely unrelated variables*. This is because they're static; static things never override, because they belong to the class, not the object. In `Shape`, when you refer to `name`, that's really shorthand for `Shape.name`. Similarly, in `Triangle`, `name` means `Triangle.name`. The *same symbol* refers to *different variables* in *different scopes*.

In this code:

```
public class Shape {
    static String name = "shape";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}

class Colour {
    static String name = "colour";
}
```

You wouldn't think for a second that the output would be "colour", would you? This is exactly the situation in the code you show. The inheritance relationship between the two classes is simply a red herring.

If you want the name to be polymorphic, then your only option is to use an instance method, because instance methods are the only things that can be polymorphic. The most concise way to do that is to inline the constants into the methods:

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Shape();
        new Triangle();
    }

    public static class Shape {
        Shape() {
            printName();
        }

        public void printName() {
            System.out.println(name());
        }

        public String name() {
            return "shape";
        }
    }

    public static class Triangle extends Shape {
        @Override
        public String name() {
            return "triangle";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a final field and set it in the constructor, but IMHO it's preferable to override the getters.

```
public static class Shape
{
        protected final String name;

        public Shape()
        {
                this("shape");
        }

        protected Shape(String name)
        {
                this.name = name;
        }

        public void printName()
        {
                System.out.println( name() );
        }

        public String name()
        {
                return name;
        }
}

public static class Triangle extends Shape
{
        public Triangle()
        {
               super("triangle");
        }
}
```